# protoc can't be installed : not find a version that satisfies the requirement protoc

Tags: protocol-buffers, object-detection-api, protoc, tensorflow1.15

i will install protoc on windows 10 (python 3.7.2)

```
pip install protoc <br/>
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement protoc<br/>
ERROR: No matching distribution found for protoc <br/>
```

what should i do? anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `protobuf` with the command `pip install protobuf`, `protoc` is just a tool that uses `protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, I think you need to install `gcpio-tools` to actually get `protoc` executable installed through `pip`. To run the `pip` installed one, you have to use `python -m grpc.tools.protoc ...` as command.

You can also install `protoc.exe` from [Protocol Buffers download page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/).